# Problems with running Nuxt 3 [3.0.0-rc.3] on Apple silicon

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, apple-silicon, nuxtjs3

I followed the [quick guide](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start) to create an app using the operating system `macOS Monterey 12.4` MacBook Pro M1 Max / Node v16.15.0 and also tried with 18.

When visiting the host `http://localhost:3000`, it repeats the error constantly [below shows the error in the terminal]. It looks like it could be a problem with the hot reload.

I tried reinstalling the node using [brew](https://brew.sh) and nvm for different node versions. This problem only **curves on apple silicon**, **not on Intel-based machines**. How can I solve this problem?

---

**Creating nuxt app :**

```
npx nuxi init nuxt-app
```

**package.json :**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.3"
  }
}
```

**After running `npm run dev` it through an error :**

```
Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-rc.3                                                                                      11:19:41
                                                                                                          11:19:41
  > Local:    http://localhost:3000/ 
  > Network:  http://172.30.1.18:3000/

✘ [ERROR] Cannot read directory "../../..": operation not permitted


 ERROR  11:19:43 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies:                                             11:19:43
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Cannot read directory "../../..": operation not permitted
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1603:15)
    at /Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1249:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1034:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (/Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1247:7)
    at /Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1356:14
    at /Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/USERNAME/nuxt-appnode_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined (repeated 20 times)


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/ufo.js?v=2227049b optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43


 ERROR  Vite Error, /_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=3f037d64 optimized info should be defined     11:19:43

ℹ Vite server warmed up in 112ms                                                                          11:19:43
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 438ms                                                                          11:19:43
✔ Vite server built in 335ms                                                                              11:19:43
✔ Nitro built in 174 ms                                                                             nitro 11:19:43
```

Comment: I don't have such issue on my M1. Maybe try to install your packages with `yarn` or maybe try another RC version of Nuxt. Working perfectly fine for me for some reason. Do you maybe have a Github repo?

Comment: Be sure that you have the proper rights on your subdirectories (`ls -l`+ `chmod`) and maybe share your installed packages.

Comment: I reinstalled Node and tried yarn, npm also updated all packages. No result.
After the new update of npm 8.11.0 no issue at all on M1 max. Finally, it works!

Vesrions I used:
- Nuxt: 3.0.0-rc.3
- Node: v16.15.0
- Npm 8.11.0

Thanks @kissu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated npm to 8.11.0, and no issue on M1 Max.

Vesrions I used:

- Nuxt: 3.0.0-rc.3
- Node: v16.15.0
- Npm 8.11.0